# Next.js - Failed to load next.config.js even after updating node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, command-line-interface

Alright, I am trying to run my next.js on local host for development by running `npx next dev` at the root of the project. Upon doing this, I get logs that a local server was started and then the command fails with this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:76651) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
Error: Not supported
```

I went to the [link mentioned](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error) and saw "This could be due to a syntax error or attempting to require/import a module that wasn't available." I cloned a template project so I know I havent made any errors in the config file.

Other SO posts mention this is due to Node JS and Next js being out of sync in versions. I updated Node JS and am now on most up to date v10.15.3.

Given this is the Next template project, What is wrong here? How I can run my project locally for easy testing?

Comment: _"I updated Node JS and am now on most up to date v10.15.3"_ - Latest Next.js version does not support Node v10. Current Node.js Active LTS is v16.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to run the project in development mode then the command is `npm run dev`

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Solved - updating node via command line didnt work. Install latest node at https://nodejs.org/en/